# Implementation of Firebase Auth with Flutter and Provider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am a bit confused about the implementation of Provider with Firebase Auth. Every tutorial seems to use different methods. 
 I have a service named `AuthService` which contains a variable `final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance`. So, I want to use the following `stream`: `AuthService.auth.onAuthStateChanged` in a widged. The question is should I use something like:

```
StreamProvider<FirebaseUser>.value(
  value: AuthService().auth.onAuthStateChanged,
  child: ...
```

or create a constructor like this:

```
Provider<AuthService>(
  create: (_) => AuthService(),
  child: ...
)
```

and access it somewhere in the widget:

```
final authService = Provider.of<AuthService>(context);<br>
final user = authService.auth.onAuthStateChanged;
```

Comment: may I know what you exactly want to achieve through `Auth`?

Comment: I want to get the current user. If the user is not logged in, `onAuthStateChanged` returns `null`.

Comment: Please check my answer, you don't need provider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use similar to this thing, If user is logged in he will lead to MainScreen() otherwise it will lead you to LoginPage(), you don't need to use
`provider`

```
Widget _handleAuth() {
    return StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
        return (!snapshot.hasData)
            ? LoginPage()
            : MainScreen();
      },
    );
```

Comment: I will definitely consider using your method. One question though, will I be able to implement Provider down the line? Will your method have any conflicts with Provider if I needed to use it?

Comment: Sure You can implement the provider in different screen, in this screen you don't need it

Answer (score 0):

The provider package exposes different types of providers, you can check all types in their page [here](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) (At the bottom of their page).

Using a provider instead of another it depends on your needs, as far I'm concerned the Provider(the first one in the list) is fine.

Comment: The question is not whether or not I should use Provider, it is how I should implement it.

Comment: But the implementation depends of the type of provider that you want to use, you have talked about StreamProvider and Provider, these are part of the same provider but they depend on your needs. I'm sorry if i did'nt got it